# Full Outer Join Subqueries works until last part then ORA-013113

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been task to implement a query that will identify and provide datetime marks using a specific date and time range for each user. Basically first scan last scan throughout the entire shift at specific intervals.

I set a UI that prompts user for date time that will be used within the query and then smaller subqueries to parse out the data I need. Individually every works as I expect but when I get to the last set it breaks and I encounter the following error:

> ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

I can't seem to work around this or think of an alternative way to structure the query to what I need.

I need help w/ either a better method of achieving the same results or a fix to what I already have in place.

This is for an Oracle database 12c

```
With
UI As
( Select
    -- Deactivate UI While testing
     @('Start of Shift', #DATETIME) sDATE,
     @('End of Shift', #DATETIME) EDate
      @Oracle(From Dual) -- Oracle don't allow "Select from Nothing"
)


Select s90.uname, Trim(s90.fname)||' '||(s90.lname) "_Full Name", MIN(FRST.datetimecol) "_Day Start", Max(FRST.datetimecol) "_Before 1st break"
, MIN(SCND.datetimecol) "_After 1st Break", Max(SCND.datetimecol) "_Before Lunch"
, MIN(THRD.datetimecol) "_After Lunch", MAX(THRD.datetimecol) "_Before Last Break"
, MIN(FRTH.datetimecol) "_After Last Break", MAX(FRTH.datetimecol) "_End of Shift"

From

(Select T1.Username, t1.datetimecol
From
syslogtable T1
where datetimecol > (Select sdate from UI) and datetimecol < (Select edate from UI) and to_char(datetimecol, 'hh24:mi:ss') >= '05:00:00' and to_char(datetimecol, 'hh24:mi:ss') <= '08:00:59') FRST

Full Outer Join

(Select T2.Username, t2.datetimecol
From
syslogtable T2 
where datetimecol > (Select sdate from UI) and datetimecol < (Select edate from UI) and to_char(datetimecol, 'hh24:mi:ss') >= '08:00:00' and to_char(datetimecol, 'hh24:mi:ss') <= '10:00:59') SCND
On FRST.Username = SCND.Username

-- code continues in same format then I close out the fourth part w/ below
-- from frst to thrd - no issues but when add frth it stops
,
usermastertable s90

Where FRST.Username = s90.uname


Group By s90.uname, Trim(s90.fname)||' '||(s90.lname) 

Order by s90.uname
```

I expect to receive usernamecol, full name then the date/time stamps in the applicable columns

Comment: You say this is for Oracle 12c, but your SQL statement appears to be non-Oracle (you would never use things like `@('Start of Shift', #DATETIME)` in Oracle). That UI subquery doesn't look right.

Comment: Ok I appreciate your input but this has worked in providing one prompt and called out in the subqueries by (select sdate from ui). Also I ran a db check before posting and it showed as having oracle database 12c enterprise edition 12.1.0.2.0 64 bit

Comment: Where are you running the above query from? Is it from some other code, directly in a GUI like SQL Developer, Toad, etc, or in SQL*Plus?

Comment: It's not like sql developer even though I wish it was; the company I work for has their own db management system but uses Oracle /pl sql as its core. All I really have to work with is the coding section, result section and an execute button before saving/ publishing for others to utilize.  I can link this to hyperion and go through the process of creating queries and linking tables but haven't gone that route for this project yet

Comment: At a guess, this query is hitting some Oracle bug that's causing the session closure. If you can update your question to add in sample input data in your table(s) and the expected output of the query, we may be able to rewrite the query so that it doesn't hit that issue. Those full outer joins seem odd to me. Bonus points if you can get a test case set up in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18)

Comment: I just noticed I had the question still up. It turns out that the query in itself was fine but because it was performing many individual lookups on a large and growing table it would reach it's limit and timeout.
To overcome this I wound up splitting this in separate queries and added some case when logic to account for multiple shifts. I also made a third that would prompt for user to get the whole nitty gritty on that specific user.